# Kotlin ArrayAdapter Error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied

Tags: android, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I am new to Kotlin for Android development. While following along a tutorial project, I needed to use `ArrayAdapter` with a custom class. Building the project failed with error.

> The MainActivity.kt class throwing the error:

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
    }

    val dm = DataManager()
    val adapterCourses = ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo>(
        context = this,
        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
        dm.courses.values.toList()
    )

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_settings -> true
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int, @RecentlyNonNull p2: Array<(out) CourseInfo!>!) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int, @RecentlyNonNull p3: Array<(out) CourseInfo!>!) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int, p2: Int, @RecentlyNonNull p3: (Mutable)List<CourseInfo!>!) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
public constructor ArrayAdapter<T : Any!>(@RecentlyNonNull p0: Context!, p1: Int, @RecentlyNonNull p2: (Mutable)List<CourseInfo!>!) defined in android.widget.ArrayAdapter
```

The CourseInfo Class:

```
class CourseInfo (val courseId: String, val title: String)
```

The DataManager Class:

```
class DataManager {
    val courses = HashMap<String, CourseInfo>()
    val notes = ArrayList<NoteInfo>()

    init {
        initializeCourses()
    }

    private fun initializeCourses () {
        var course = CourseInfo(courseId = "android_intent", title = "Android programming with intent.")
        this.courses.set(course.courseId, course)

        course = CourseInfo(courseId = "android_async", title = "Android Async Programming and Services.")
        courses.set(course.courseId, course)

        course = CourseInfo(courseId = "java_lang", title = "Java Fundamentals: The Java Language.")
        courses.set(course.courseId, course)

        course = CourseInfo(courseId = "java_core", title = "Java Fundamentals: The Core Platforms.")
        courses.set(course.courseId, course)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line the error occurs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Named arguments are not allowed for non-kotlin functions.**

The problem is since you are invoking **java** **ArrayAdapter** constructor in kotlin file. you won't be able to provide argument label to it.

so following simple correction would resolve the issue.(Notice here, I removed context label in first argument.)

```
val adapterCourses = ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            dm.courses.values.toList())
```

Comment: Thank you @Vipul Shah for the explanation. The error is gone!

Comment: This seems to be true, but I can't find it in any documentation about it. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe too late but maybe it helps someone. If you are working with Fragments it will not be resolved by the checked answer. You must call the activity context like this.

```
val adapter = activity?.let {
        ArrayAdapter<String>(
            it,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            campaignsType
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

call requireContext() in place of context parameter

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code

```
val courseList:List<CourseInfo>= dm.courses.values.toList()
val adapterCourses = ArrayAdapter<CourseInfo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,courseList)
```

Answer (score 0):

val adapters = activity?.let { ArrayAdapter(it.applicationContext, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, stringArray) } as SpinnerAdapter