# Erorr when using ArrayList (initalCapacity)

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist

I have an `adapter` class and in which I `initialise` a map as follows:

```
internal class MyAdapter(private var itemList: List<Items>) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

    private var itemStates: MutableMap<Int, ArrayList<Boolean>> = mutableMapOf()

    init {
        itemList.forEachIndexed { index, itemObject->

            val capacity  = if(itemObject.getItemTYPE() == Item.ITEM_TYPE.FOOD) 3 else 5

            itemStates[index] = ArrayList(initialCapacity = capacity) //error is shown here
        }
    }
```

Everything else seems fine, but when I run this, I get the following error:

> None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:

> public final fun  ():
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* =
> java.util.ArrayList */ defined in
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList
>
> public final fun  (p0: (MutableCollection<out
> Boolean!>..Collection<Boolean!>?)):
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* =
> java.util.ArrayList */ defined in
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList
>
> public final fun  (p0: Int):
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList /* =
> java.util.ArrayList */ defined in
> kotlin.collections.ArrayList

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question to show the _full_ error message.

Comment: @Thomas I have updated it

Comment: you have to put some constant value here. it will not use dynamic initialise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the error message, the parameter is named `p0` and not `initialCapacity`. This is probably happening because `ArrayList` is imported straight from Java (see the `= java.util.ArrayList` part), and in Java, parameter names aren't part of the function signature. Probably the JAR that your compiler is referencing has had the names optimized away. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52948853/kotlin-arrayadapter-error-none-of-the-following-functions-can-be-called-with-th).

Rather than writing `ArrayList(p0 = capacity)`, I would just write `ArrayList(capacity)` so you don't depend on the argument name anymore.